# Unity in Prism using WPF

Tags: unity-container, prism

In Prism can we have another instance of unity at module level to register the classes in a particular module.so that i will not load the application level unity with so many classes in different modules.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a scoped unity container.  Here's an article on it:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/07/26/using-unity-container-hierarchies.aspx

This would allow your users to get all of the types registered in the "Parent" container, but also allow them to add their own without affecting the "Parent" container.

HTH,
Anderson

Answer (score 0):

The answer in NO. You can't , it's against Unity infrastructure.